# poner un input check dependiendo de un condicional

Tags: html, checkbox

estoy tratando de hacer que un checkbox tenga la opcion checked dependiendo de un campo de mi base de datos, si es 1 que sea checked sino, no lo tenga, para esto estoy usando un condicional, utilizo el foreach para llenar las filas de la tabla:

codigo

```
     <?php foreach($approved->result() as $key){ ?>


  <tr class="text-center">
  <td class="blue"><?php echo $key->request_num_case;?></td>
  <td class="blue"><?php echo $key->request_made_by;?></td>
  <td class="blue"><?php echo $key->request_date;?></td>
  <td class="blue"><?php echo $key->fk_roster_salesforcename;?></td>
  <td class="blue"><?php echo $key->fk_incidence_name;?></td>
  <td class="blue"><?php echo $key->request_incidence_date;?></td>
  <td class="blue"><?php echo $key->request_updated_by;?></td>
  <td class="blue"><?php echo $key->request_auth_date;?></td>
  <td class=" <?php
    if ($key->request_resolution == "approved") {
            echo "text-success";
      }
  ?>
  "><?php $str = strtoupper($key->request_resolution); echo $str;?></td>
  <td class="blue"><?php echo $key->request_unread_buga;?></td>
  <?php if($key->request_unread_buga == "1"){?>
    <td class="blue"><input type="checkbox" checked></td>
  <?php} else{?>
    <td class="blue"><input type="checkbox"></td>
  <?php}?>
  <td class="blue">
    <form class="" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Buga/detailIncidence" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="CaseNumber" value="<?php echo $key->request_num_case;?>" class="display">
    <input type="submit" name="detailsBtn" value="Details .." class="btn tlBack whitecol-lg-2 white" id="detailsBtn">
    </form>
  </td>
```

me sale este error cuando ponga las siguientes lineas:

```
  <?php if($key->request_unread_buga == "1"){?>
  <td class="blue"><input type="checkbox" checked></td>
  <?php} else{?>
  <td class="blue"><input type="checkbox"></td>
  <?php}?>
```

error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sino pongo esas lineas no me sale error y como ven si me iprime lo que hay en la columna (request_unread_buga, que es la que dice check) que es de la que depende el condicional.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con el codigo del condicional segun este caso deberia salir los checkbox son checked ya que ninguna fila de esa columna tiene el valor 1, no me deberia salir ese error o en que estoy fallando, y realmemnte necesito esos checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes separar los tags de inicio y fin de php de su contenido:

```
<?php if($key->request_unread_buga == "1"){ ?>
<td class="blue"><input type="checkbox" checked></td>
<?php }else{ ?>
<td class="blue"><input type="checkbox"></td>
<?php } ?>
```

Evita hacer esto `<?php{` o `{?>`